# Pixel trail/ after image using tkinter Canvas.move()

Tags: tkinter, pixel, game-development, move, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to make the game Alien invaders in Python using tkinter. Whilst trying to make the aliens move across the screen I've found they leave a pixel trail/ after image as below. I used canvas.move for other objects such as the player and its lasers, which do not experience the same issue. any fixes?
(instructions for alien movement are not complete, I want to solve this issue first, and just make them move to the right without the pixel effect)
Sorry I'm relatively new to coding and very inexperience with tkinter/ any sort of game creation. Any help is much appreciated.

my code (just for aliens and not for player or laser) is

```
from tkinter import * # Graphical user interface (GUI) module as part of standard library
import random
import time 

GAME_WIDTH = 1000
GAME_HEIGHT = 500
ALIEN_SPEED = 100
ALIEN_SIZE = 50
BACKGROUND_COLOUR = "black"

score = 0 #initial score
direction = "right" #initial direction
aliens = [] #global variable to create a row of aliens 

#initial set up 
window = Tk() #from tkinter to create the window
window.title("Alien Game")
label = Label(window, text = f"Score: {score}", font = ('consolas', 40))
label.pack()

canvas = Canvas(window, background= BACKGROUND_COLOUR, height= GAME_HEIGHT, width= GAME_WIDTH)
canvas.pack()



class Alien: #create individual alien body
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.body = []
        self.face = canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x+ALIEN_SIZE, self.y+ALIEN_SIZE, fill = 'yellow', outline='', width=0)
        self.eye1 = canvas.create_rectangle(self.x+0.2*ALIEN_SIZE, self.y+0.2*ALIEN_SIZE, self.x+0.4*ALIEN_SIZE, self.y+0.4*ALIEN_SIZE, fill = 'black', outline='', width=0)
        self.eye2 = canvas.create_rectangle(self.x+0.6*ALIEN_SIZE, self.y+0.2*ALIEN_SIZE, self.x+0.8*ALIEN_SIZE, self.y+0.4*ALIEN_SIZE, fill = 'black', outline='', width=0)
        self.mouth = canvas.create_rectangle(self.x+0.2*ALIEN_SIZE, self.y+0.8*ALIEN_SIZE, self.x+0.8*ALIEN_SIZE, self.y+ALIEN_SIZE, fill = 'black', outline='', width=0)
        self.body.extend((self.face, self.eye1, self.eye2, self.mouth))


def create_aliens(): # create multiple aliens in a row
    for i in range (int((GAME_WIDTH/(2*ALIEN_SIZE))*0.8)):
        aliens.append(Alien(x = i*2*ALIEN_SIZE, y = ALIEN_SIZE/2))
    return aliens

def move_aliens(): #move row of alien across screen
    global direction
    aliens = create_aliens()
    if direction == 'right':
        if aliens[-1].x <= (GAME_WIDTH-ALIEN_SIZE): # test if reached screen edge 
            for alien in aliens:
                for body_part in alien.body:
                    canvas.move(body_part, 10, 0)
                
        else:
            direction = 'left'
    elif direction == 'left':
        if aliens[0].x >= (0):
            for alien in aliens:
                canvas.move(alien.body, -5, 0)
                alien.x -=5
        else:
            direction = 'right'
    print (direction)
    window.after(ALIEN_SPEED, move_aliens)

#to centre the window on the screen (top left is position 0,0)
window.update()
x= int((window.winfo_screenwidth() - window.winfo_width())/2) #centre x position
y = int((window.winfo_screenheight() - window.winfo_height())/2) #centre y position
window.geometry(f'{window.winfo_width()}x{window.winfo_height()}+{x}+{y-30}') #format of (window width) x (window height) at + (position width) + (position height)

move_aliens()

window.mainloop()
```

[image: how aliens start]
[after they start moving to the right 10 pixels at a time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/101yN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You create new set of aliens whenever `move_aliens()` is called.  Create the set of aliens once outside the function:

```py
def move_aliens(): #move row of alien across screen
    global direction
    ### don't create set of aliens here
    #aliens = create_aliens()
    if direction == 'right':
        if aliens[-1].x < (GAME_WIDTH-ALIEN_SIZE): # test if reached screen edge
            for alien in aliens:
                for body_part in alien.body:
                    canvas.move(body_part, 10, 0)
                alien.x += 10
        else:
            direction = 'left'
    elif direction == 'left':
        if aliens[0].x > 0:
            for alien in aliens:
                for body_part in alien.body:
                    canvas.move(body_part, -5, 0)
                alien.x -= 5
        else:
            direction = 'right'
    print (direction)
    window.after(ALIEN_SPEED, move_aliens)

...

aliens = create_aliens()
move_aliens()

...
```